# Converting DateAdd and Format code from VB6 to C#

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

I have the following code in vb -

```
tAvailableDate = DateAdd("d", 21, Format(Now, gDATEFORMAT))
```

I am attempting to convert this into C#.

I have converted this so far -

```
tAvailableDate = DateAdd("d", 21, Format (DateTime.Now, Global.gDATEFORMAT));
```

But I cannot find a replacement for the `DateAdd()` or `Format()` feature.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you could tell us that, you would only need people who know .NET, not people who know .NET *and* VB6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`DateAdd` is an old VB6 method that was carried over into VB.NET for backwards compatibility.  You could get it to work in C# as well if you included the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace in your C# project, but I wouldn't recommend using the method in C# or VB.NET.  Here's how you should be doing it (it's easier to read too):

```
tAvailableDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(21);
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. As a follow up I also have in a SQL string (still vb6) - Format(tAvailableDate, gDATEFORMAT) 
For C# i can simply make that - tAvailableDate . ?

Comment: To convert a `DateTime` object to a string, use the `ToString` method, such as: `tAvailableDate.ToString(gDATEFORMAT)`

Answer (score 11):

My VB6 is a bit rusty, but if I recall, you're trying to add 21 days.  So here's what you want to do:

```
tAvailableDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(21);
```

**UPDATE**

You mentioned that you converted the variable to a `DateTime` from a `string`.  If you need to get it back to a `string` (which it looks like you might from another comment), then you want to call:

```
tAvailableDate.ToString("[format string]");
```

For help on formatting your string the way you want, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Comment: +1. Yes, it makes no sense to convert to string with Format and then to try to add days. Days can be added to dates but not to strings. Probably it works with VB6, beacuse VB6 automatically converts the string back to `Date` and thus masks this error! But if it converts it back by using another culture than specified in `gDATEFORMAT` it could produce an error (by inverting days and months for instance).

Comment: Thanks for your help. That code worked perfectly. To do away with the Format in VB6 when writing my C# code I declared tAvailable date as a DateTime as opposed to a string.

Comment: As a follow up I also have in a SQL string (still vb6) - Format(tAvailableDate, gDATEFORMAT) For C# i can simply make that - tAvailableDate . ?

Answer (score 0):

I have thought over your problem and there is an aspect that I missed yesterday. I thought that the `Format` function made no sense, but, even if it look strange, it can make sense. Let me explain.

In VB6 we have

```vb
tAvailableDate = DateAdd("d", 21, Format(Now, gDATEFORMAT))
```

Why does it look strange (or even wrong)? `Now` is a `Date`. `Format` converts this date to a `String` (well to a `Variant` containing a `String` to be precise), but `DateAdd` needs a `Date` parameter in order to be able to add days. `DateAdd` is declared like this:

```vb
Function DateAdd(Interval As String, Number As Double, Date)
```

Instead of giving a warning or a compiler error, VB6 silently converts this string back to a `Date` and passes it to `DateAdd`. So my first assumption was to just drop this `Format`.

BUT this `Format` can have a desired effect on the result, depending on how `gDATEFORMAT` is defined. If `gDATEFORMAT` contains only a date part, the format function will drop the time part! However this could simply be achieved by using the `Date` function instead of using the `Now` function in VB6

```vb
tAvailableDate = DateAdd("d", 21, Date)
```

or `DateTime.Today` in .NET (C# or VB.NET).

But `gDATEFORMAT` could contain only month and year. VB6  (using my Swiss locale):

```vb
Date   ==>  27.06.2012
Format(Date,"MM.yyyy")   ==>  "06.2012"
CDate(Format(Date,"MM.yyyy"))   ==>  01.06.2012
```

As you can see, formatting the date would have the effect to return the first day of the current month in this case. By adding 21 days you would always get the 22nd of the current month. This is quite different than adding 21 days to the current date! In C# you could achieve the same with

```cs
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
tAvailableDate = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 22);
```

In order to decide which approach is correct, you must either know what `gDATEFORMAT` contains or, if this is variable, format the date and then parse the resulting string to get a date again.