# Convert VB.net DateAdd into C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am not able to find the right way to convert `DateAdd` to C#. I tried Telerik and other tools to convert nothing is correct. All giving compile errors.

```vb
dtDueDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, intFreqInMonths * intIndex, nextPaymentDueDate)
dtDueDate = DateAdd("m", 1, dtDueDate)
dtDueDate = DateAdd("m", intFreqInMonths * intIndex, nextPaymentDueDate)
```

### Telerik

```cs
dtDueDate = DateTime.DateAdd(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, intFreqInMonths * intIndex, nextPaymentDueDate);
dtDueDate = DateTime.DateAdd("m", 1, dtDueDate);
dtDueDate = DateTime.DateAdd("m", intFreqInMonths * intIndex, nextPaymentDueDate);
```

Comment: What did you try?  What are the errors?  What is the intended result?

Comment: dtDueDate.AddMinutes(1)

Comment: @Bizhan Months, not minutes!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting DateAdd and Format code from VB6 to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208859/converting-dateadd-and-format-code-from-vb6-to-c-sharp)

Comment: Challenge will be to work out what it means to add a "Week of the year" to a date. ;)

Comment: Just add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and you can continue using DateAdd (from C#)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use DateAdd in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44448221/11683)

Answer (score 1):

From [DateAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.dateadd?view=netcore-3.1), "m" stands for months, so use [DateTime.AddMonths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmonths?view=netcore-3.1):

```
dtDueDate = nextPaymentDueDate.AddMonths(intFreqInMonths * intIndex);
```

Comment: FYI, the first two lines of code you posted don't matter to the end result of "dtDueDate".

Comment: OP was not asking for end result I think. All should be different samples.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime has methods for that:

```
dtDueDate = dtDueDate.AddMonths(1);
dtDueDate = nextPaymentDueDate.AddMonths(intFreqInMonths * intIndex);
```

No idea what DateInterval.WeekOfYear means, you can explain it maybe.